# Excel VBA : conditional formatting of sheet1 cells from sheet2 values in excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

Issue 1: 
I tried to format cell A1 ( color format) in sheet1 from sheet2 A1 with something following formula:

```
=Sheet2!A1>0.5
```

The excel warned that you can not use formula from other sheet or workbook for conditional formula.

Is there is any VBA solution to this problem?

Issue 2: in process of looking alternative to issue 1 
I can rearrange the data (I have 6000 columns) in the way that

```
Sheet3$A1 = Sheet1$A1, Sheet3$B1 = Sheet2$A1
```

Means that the first column in sheet 1 and sheet 2 will be first and second column in sheet 3. Is there is any easy solution to this, perhaps using vba.

Once this is acheived I want to apply the condition format in pairs

A column formatted based on B, C column formatted based on D coumn and so on ......till all 6000 pairs are done...again I am looking for automation.

Sorry I have limited knowledge to Excel VBA, your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a work around for conditional format references on another sheet:  use a `Named Range`

In your case, try this
Name the whole of column A in Sheet 2 as `Sheet2_ColA`
Apply conditional format formula to cells in Sheet 1

```
=INDEX(Sheet2_ColA,ROW())>0.5
```

**Edit**

to apply to whole sheet, choose a name that doesn't look like a reserved word (eg `AllSheet2`) and change formula to index rows and columns

```
=INDEX(AllSheet2,ROW(),COLUMN())>0.5
```

Comment: thank you for your input, it is indeed helpful. I tried and works for column. As I have > 6000 variables to workout, I wonder if there is way to conditionally format whole sheet 1 based on whole sheet 2, I tried the following formula: In defined whole sheet2 as Sheet2, and the formula was: = INDEX(sheet2, ROW())) > 0.5, but do not work....